# how to create a non-ascii file using redirection with `sh -c`?

Tags: ubuntu, utf-8, debian, sh, dash-shell

The same command: `echo 1 > filename` creates different filenames:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $LANG >=с=.sh' && ls *.sh | od -c
0000000   = 321   =   .   s   h  \n
0000007
```

and

```
$ bash -c 'echo $LANG >=с=.bash' && ls *.bash | od -c
0000000   = 321 201   =   .   b   a   s   h  \n
0000012
```

Where `с` is the `U+0441` character — [CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0441/index.htm). It is clear that `sh` eats the second byte in the `utf-8` encoding.

```
$ ls *sh
=?=.sh  =с=.bash
```

`$LANG` in both cases is:

```
$ cat *sh
en_US.utf8
en_US.utf8
```

`sh` is linked to `dash` on my system:

```
$ apt-cache show dash | grep -i version
Version: 0.5.5.1-7ubuntu1
```

`stty iutf8` is set.

Is there any setting that allows `dash` not to mangle multi-byte characters?

I don't see any mentions about character encoding in the manual:

```
$ man dash | grep -i encoding
$ man dash | grep -Pi 'multi.*byte'
```

#### Update

The second byte `'\201'` of the `'с'` character in utf-8 encoding is
`-127` as signed char (or `129` as unsigned char) in C.

The search in the source code (`apt-get source dash`) for `-127` results in:

```
src/parser.h:38:#define CTL_FIRST -127      /* first 'special' character */
src/parser.h:39:#define CTLESC -127     /* escape next character */
```

Search for `CTLESC` leads to `rmescapes()` macros that leads to the
following fragment from `src/expand.c:expandarg()`:

```
/*
 * TODO - EXP_REDIR
 */
if (flag & EXP_FULL) {
    ifsbreakup(p, &exparg);
    *exparg.lastp = NULL;
    exparg.lastp = &exparg.list;
    expandmeta(exparg.list, flag);
} else {
    if (flag & EXP_REDIR) /*XXX - for now, just remove escapes */
        rmescapes(p);
    sp = (struct strlist *)stalloc(sizeof (struct strlist));
    sp->text = p;
    *exparg.lastp = sp;
    exparg.lastp = &sp->next;
}
```

`TODO` and `XXX` hints that a more recent version might
help. `debian/dash.README.source` points to:

```
$ git clone http://smarden.org/git/dash.git/
$ cd dash
```

There are two branches:

```
$ git br
* debian-sid
  release+patches
```

On `debian-sid` the escape byte is removed. On the `release+patches`
branch `grep` finds the missing byte.

```
$ ./configure
$ make && rm *.dash -f; ./dash -c 'echo 1 >fсf.dash' && 
> ls *.dash | od -c | grep 201
```

`git diff debian-sid...release+patches` shows that `rmescapes()` was
removed in `release-patches`:

```
diff --git a/src/expand.c b/src/expand.c
index e4c4c8b..f2f964c 100644
--- a/src/expand.c
+++ b/src/expand.c
...
@@ -213,8 +210,6 @@ expandarg(union node *arg, struct arglist *arglist, int flag)
                exparg.lastp = &exparg.list;
                expandmeta(exparg.list, flag);
        } else {
-               if (flag & EXP_REDIR) /*XXX - for now, just remove escapes */
-                       rmescapes(p);
                sp = (struct strlist *)stalloc(sizeof (struct strlist));
                sp->text = p;
                *exparg.lastp = sp;
@@ -412,7 +407,7 @@ lose:
 }
```

It is unclear whether these changes will be included in `dash 0.5.6.1` on Ubuntu.

For now the only way to make the command:

```
$ sh -c 'echo 1 >fсf.dash' &&  ls *.dash | od -c | grep 201
```

to work is to reconfigure `sh` back to `bash`:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the several shells (or versions) I tried, only Dash and Busybox Ash failed.

```
$ for sh in bash2.05b bash3.2 bash4.0 bash4.1 bash4.2 dash zsh ksh pdksh mksh ash; do $sh -c 'locale > с.$0'; done
$ csh -c 'locale > с.csh'
$ fish -c 'locale > с.fish'
$ ls -1
?.ash
?.dash
с.bash2.05b
с.bash3.2
с.bash4.0
с.bash4.1
с.bash4.2
с.csh
с.fish
с.ksh
с.mksh
с.pdksh
с.zsh
```

The contents were all the same.

From [`man dash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash):

> Only features designated by POSIX, plus a few Berkeley extensions, are being incorporated
>        into this shell.  This man page is not intended to be a tutorial or a
>        complete specification of the shell.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap06.html) says:

> The POSIX locale contains the characters in Portable Character Set , which have the properties listed in LC_CTYPE . In other locales, the presence, meaning, and representation of any additional characters are locale-specific.

and

> Wide-character codes for other characters are locale and implementation-defined. ... POSIX.1-2008 provides no means of defining a wide-character codeset.

Comment: the second branch `release+patches` from the `dash` package git repository http://smarden.org/git/dash.git/ works but the default `debian-sid` doesn't. I've update the question with details.